# how to stop blur closing the block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you click on the  top input the red block shows. How do I stop it that when you click on the red block or its input then the block hides.  My codes only works in chrome but not firefox or ie. can you please help

http://jsfiddle.net/n9Mbh/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $txtMain = $('#txtMain');
                var $popupInput = $('#popupInput');
                var $popup = $('#popup');



                $popup.hide();

                $txtMain.focus(function() {$popup.show();});
                $popupInput.focus(function() {$popup.show();});
                $popup.focus(function() {$popup.show();});

                $txtMain.blur(function() {$popup.hide();});
                $popupInput.blur(function() {$popup.hide();});
                $popup.blur(function() {$popup.hide();});


            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <br /><br />


        <input type="text" id="txtMain" />

            <div id="popup" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;" tabindex="5"><br /><br />
                <input type="text" id="popupInput">
            </div>


                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />

        <input type="text" id="test"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Firefox, when you click on $popupInput, you are first firing off blur on whatever input you just left, so it hides. This prevents focus on $popupInput. Or rather, it may fire focus on the new element and then blur on the old element

Comment: Duplicate of your own question [div is not getting focus in time: blur fires before the focus out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270504/div-is-not-getting-focus-in-time-blur-fires-before-the-focus-out)

Comment: i never got an answer

Answer (score 0):

1) The problem is the below line

```
$txtMain.blur(function() {$popup.hide();});
```

once it focusOut the `$txtMain`, the popup is getting hide.

Try this

```
$txtMain.blur(function () {
                    if (!$('#popup').is(':visible')) {
                        $popup.hide();
                    } 
                });
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9Mbh/4/) in Firefox

Hope you understand the logic behind.

Comment: Why would you have that empty if statement? Why not just invert it and have $popup.hide()?

Comment: @danrhul First I wanted to show OP an example to solve is problem, `if (!$('#popup').is(':visible')) {
                        $popup.hide();
                    }`  Adding a negation is not a big deal right.  Anyway I like to do.  Let me update the answer.

Comment: thanks for the the reply - but now how do I close  the red block if I click on any other element except $txtMain,$popupInput,$popup . thanks so much for the help and I dont want to bind any events out side if possible.

Comment: The statement is also useless in it's entirety since `:visible`/`:hidden` is determined by the `display` property so the only time it's `!:visible`or `:hidden` is when `display` is `none` and `.hide()` will have no effect ...